# MYSQL Select within same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that I need a MYSQL Select statement so I can find the corrupt data and manually fix it.

Sample table

```
TABLE_A
id | type | value1 | value2
 1 |  10  | 123    | 987  
 2 |  10  | 123    | 987
 3 |  10  | 123    | 789
 4 |  20  | 123    | 987
 5 |  20  | 456    | 987
 6 |  30  | 123    | null
 7 |  30  | 123    | null
 8 |  40  | 123    | 987
```

I need a select statement that will list records that if they have the same "type" and value1 is not the same and/or value2 not the same.

For Example

- ID 1,2,3 - will be displayed because value2 is different in id 3 and they have the same "type"
- ID 4,5 will be displayed because value1 is different and they have the same "type"
- ID 6,7 will NOT be displayed because value1 and value2 are the same for the same "type"
- ID 8 will NOT be displayed because there is only one with this type.

I have been trying to get my head around this for days and need some help.  Thanks

Comment: type is specified ? ( e.g `type`= '$type'  or query must group results by type ? )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id as problem_id
FROM TABLE_A as a JOIN TABLE_A as b
ON a.type = b.type
WHERE a.value1 <> b.value1 OR a.value2 <> b.value2
GROUP BY problem_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE type IN (SELECT type FROM TABLE_A GROUP BY `type`, `value1`, `value2` HAVING count(value1) > 1 OR count(value2) > 1)
```

Comment: excellent that work in the test.  I will try it in the main database now.  Thanks @Tudor!

Comment: An upvote and accept answer are a great to show your gratitude :)

Comment: Just tested and this does not compare the value1 or value2

Comment: It should `group by` them if they are different, the `COUNT` function returns the number of different items